# Ubuntu mate GNOME freezes on startup

Tags: 16.04, gnome, mate

when I start my laptop with Ubuntu Mate 16.04, and after I login.. GNOME always freezes or becomes unresponsive.

To fix this, I can restart GNOME with `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and then back to my screen with `Ctrl+Alt+F7`.

But that is not the solution I want. I just want to fix this unresponsiveness. The first step would be to debug this, but I dont know where to start. 
Does gnome report any log files on this kind of behaviour?

EDIT:
based on the comments, I ran `ubuntu-support-status` and found that most of my packages (75%) are still supported.

Thanks. I did not know this, it might be wise indeed to switch to a different version that ís supported.

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Ubuntu-MATE for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.  https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-16-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/19425

Comment: (also GNOME in 16.04 was only a flavor, thus is EOL as well.  GNOME on 18.04 is the default desktop so it'll get 5 years of supported life when you *release-upgrade* to 18.04; Unity on 18.04 only has 3 years of supported life)

Comment: FYI:  Yes your base packages are still supported; GNOME shares loads of packages with Unity 7 (supported still on 16.04) so those receive updates, let alone your 16.04 base is still supported.  The other negative for getting help is many Ubuntu people may not answer; whilst it's our own choice, we are encouraged to not support EOL software/users as that support only encourages using the un-patched potentially insecure packages; anyone who has skill to backport the fixes themselves won't be seeking support anyway. I didn't *close vote*, but I ignored your question, others may do the same.

Comment: @guiverc thanks for the response! That makes a lot of sense :)

Comment: @guiverc The support status is not a problem here, I think. I run MATE 16.04 LTS on 150 machines, and do not really care about EOL as the core components still get security updates. It just works and works great.

Comment: @zwep How much RAM do you have? What is your CPU and video adapter? Am I understand correctly that installation medium was Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS and you are currently running GNOME Shell on it? Did you tried GNOME FlashBack? Does MATE run faster on this hardware?